Generate response based on date provide in Angular
I have a JSON reponse.
Response JSON:
[
  {
    "price": 388,
    "created_date": "2019-07-30T17:01:38",
    "created_user": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "price": 511,
    "created_date": "2021-02-25T19:19:55",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "price": 592,
    "created_date": "2021-09-07T08:10:41",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "price": 622,
    "created_date": "2022-01-17T15:37:41",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "price": 672,
    "created_date": "2022-02-06T13:34:35",
    "created_user": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "price": 640,
    "created_date": "2024-05-08T15:51:02",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  }
]

Input Pass Date:
InputPassdate = "2023-05-11T00:00:00"
When I passed "InputPassdate" then it search greater dates values within the response and generate new response include previous object data with "created_date" : "InputPassdate" date in below output.
Expected Output:
[
  {
    "price": 672,
    "created_date": "2023-05-11T00:00:00",
    "created_user": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "price": 640,
    "created_date": "2024-05-08T15:51:02",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  }
]


please share what you have tried

First we get the index using findIndex, then if index is greater than zero we take the previous element, update the date to desired date, finally add it to the first element of output, then we use slice specify the found index as start index, get all the values and push it also!


const data = [{
    "price": 388,
    "created_date": "2019-07-30T17:01:38",
    "created_user": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "price": 511,
    "created_date": "2021-02-25T19:19:55",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "price": 592,
    "created_date": "2021-09-07T08:10:41",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "price": 622,
    "created_date": "2022-01-17T15:37:41",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  },
  {
    "price": 672,
    "created_date": "2022-02-06T13:34:35",
    "created_user": "PQR"
  },
  {
    "price": 640,
    "created_date": "2024-05-08T15:51:02",
    "created_user": "ABCD"
  }
]
// Input Pass Date:
const inputPassdate = "2023-05-11T00:00:00"
// find the source Index
const foundIndex = data.findIndex((item) => new Date(item.created_date) > new Date(inputPassdate));
let newData = null;
const mergedData = [];
// if index not -1 or zero update the previous element
if (foundIndex > 0) {
  newData = { ...data[foundIndex - 1] };
  newData.created_date = inputPassdate;
  mergedData.push(newData);
}
if(foundIndex > -1) {
    mergedData.push(...structuredClone(data.slice(foundIndex)));
}

console.log('mergedData', mergedData)



